# Is a SRID an attribute of geometry or geometry column?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, geometry, srid

I'm not an expert. Yesterday I found out that SRID in PostGIS is property of the column - an actual constraint that is even stored in `pg_constraints` table and then retrieved through `geometry_columns` view. Previously I thought that SRID is set and stored per geometry record.

So given that, I now have several questions:

1. If it's an actual constraint why it's not enforced - e.g. why is that I can still write into the column a geometry with any SRID?
2. Why methods like `ST_SRID` or `ST_SETSRID` accept geometry as an argument rather than column name?
3. Also currently to fetch the geometries from DB we use local hardcoded map of SRIDs by region, can't we use SRIDs from `geometry_columns` instead?
4. What's the point of storing a SRID per column like that if it's not even used for anything anywhere?

Comment: Read this https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html, it may answer some of your questions. It has some errors but it is not as heavy as  http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=25355 and http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=25354 but I recommend to read them also.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: A column is a *data type container*, strictly typed to the *(C) base data type* it was created with (either new or via `ALTER COLUMN`); the system will enforce all inherent constraints of that *data type* on `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, including their *typemods*. Assuming your column is registered in the system relations: if it is of type `GEOMETRY`, it will accept **all equal types, not considering their *typemods***; but if your column is of type `GEOMETRY(4326)`, the system **will enforce the CRS *typemod***. The *typemods* are property of the type, and a column is defined by these types.

Comment: @IanTurton these are very simple and very interrelated questions. I doubt they will make any sense without context or each other.